# searching for a list in a list of ordered dictionaries

Tags: python, ordereddictionary

So I have a list of ordered dictionaries which all have 'name' keys which take a string as a value and then a series of other keys which take integers as values. I also have a list of integers separate from the list of ordered dictionaries. I would like to search through the list of ordered dictionaries and see if there are any dictionaries which have all the integers in the list, and if so, what the 'name' value in that list is. Is there any way to do this?

I.e. i have a list of dictionaries with dictionaries like so:

```
dict = OrderedDict({('name' : 'John'), ('int1': 5), ('int2': 3), ('int3': 1)}), OrderedDict({('name': 'Jack'), ('int1': 1), ('int2': 6), ('int3': 7)})
```

and then a list of integers like: `list = [3, 2, 5]`

and if there is a match between the list and the integers in any of the ordered dictionaries, I would like to get the name returned (so in the above case, John).

This may be very basic in which case I apologise, I'm very new to python and coding in general. I've been searching for hours but I haven't found anything I can understand.

Comment: How did you end up with the code sample in your question? It's not valid Python at all.

Comment: Also, is it a mistake that the list `[3, 2, 5]` returns `John`? The integer values stored for `John` are `5`, `3` and `1`.

Comment: Sorry, this question is a complete mess. Yes I did mean that the integer values for John would be 2, 3 and 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right (not that the example data, or the result for John is correct), you may be looking for

```
dicts = [
    {"name": "John", "int1": 5, "int2": 3, "int3": 1},
    {"name": "Jack", "int1": 1, "int2": 6, "int3": 7},
    {"name": "Mallory", "int1": 1, "int2": 6, "int3": 3},
]


def find_with_keyset(dicts, keyset):
    for dict in dicts:
        if all(
            key in dict and dict[key] == value
            for (key, value) in keyset.items()
        ):
            yield dict


def find_first_with_keyset(dicts, keyset):
    for result in find_with_keyset(dicts, keyset):
        return result


for match in find_with_keyset(dicts, {"int2": 6}):
    print(match["name"])

print("---")

print(find_first_with_keyset(dicts, {"int1": 5, "int2": 3, "int3": 1}))
```

This prints out

```
Jack
Mallory
---
{'name': 'John', 'int1': 5, 'int2': 3, 'int3': 1}
```

The idea is that the `find_with_keyset` generator function filters a given iterable of dicts based on a key subset; for ease-of-use there's `find_first_with_keyset` which will return the first match, or None.

To turn `[1, 2, 3]` to `{'int1': 1, ...}` you can use e.g. `{f'key{i}': value for (i, value) in enumerate([1, 2, 3], 1)}`.